# Site is almost entirely unnusable in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a site that I built that looks great in Safari, Firefox and Chrome on the mac. However, my client informed me there was nothing on the site. When I look at IE (any version) with an emulator, virtually nothing shows up on the site. Even basic stuff like  background color isn't working. I've installed a few plugins (IE7-JS, Selectivizr for WordPress, WP IE Enhancer and Modernizer) and played around with various Doctype settings. I've only managed to make the video area disappear. I've had pages with bits that didn't show up in IE but this is ridiculous. I have no time or desire to entirely (re)write the css on this. I do have to make it mostly work as the client is not at all tech-savvy and (of course) uses IE. Any suggestions on how to bludgeon this horrid thing into line? The site is cope24.com. I had posted this on the wordpress stack site but was told it was a purely css/js problem. Here's screen shots from Firefox and and an IE emulator.[image: IE View]

[image: mac view]

Comment: use google chrome frame: http://www.google.com/chromeframe/

Comment: this is for Windows only - I am mac.  Also, it is a user-end plugin and I can't force users to install it!

Comment: I don't think Google Chrome Frame is a suitable answer as this doesn't help general viewers using IE.  For what it's worth, the site appears fine in IE10 so you could just put a notice on asking IE users to upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. Neither of the emulators I tried had 10 yet so I wasn't sure if it worked there or not.  I think I'll just install a plugin that says to upgrade to 10.

Comment: You can use tools like netrenderer to check what it looks like in different IE versions (http://netrenderer.com/). That site (cope24) fails in IE7 and IE8 and IE9. It looks fine in IE 10. I was just going to say PUNT on IE7 (it's ancient anyway, and has many more issues than 8/9) and tell your client to upgrade, but if it fails in 8/9 too, you have more work to do. Check out stuff like http://caniuse.com/ to tell what features go with what browsers (I suspect your doing HTML5/CSS3 stuff, which doesn't work on IE until 10).

Comment: Microsoft has made Virtual Disk Images of windows available specifically for testing IE.  One set of downloads is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575.  You can use an image for 90 days, then you just restart with a new image.

Comment: None of these are available for mac. I have only found emulators that are via browsers (netrenderer, browserstack).

Answer (score 0):

Well, alrighty then.  Apparently I have a total fix for by removing this teeny bit of IE SPECIFIC CSS:
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius=3,MakeShadow=true,ShadowOpacity=0.30)";

It was creating a gray blur that was covering most of the page, so stuff was there, just hidden.